# Balanced, center-free set.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, computational-geometry, discrete-geometry

We say that a finite set $\mathcal{S}$ of points in the plane is **balanced** if, for any two different points $A$ and $B$ in $\mathcal{S}$, there is a point $C$ in $\mathcal{S}$ such that $AC=BC$. We say that $\mathcal{S}$ is **center-free** if for any three different points $A$, $B$ and $C$ in $\mathcal{S}$, there is no points $P$ in $\mathcal{S}$ such that $PA=PB=PC$.

1. Show that for all integers $n\ge 3$, there exists a balanced set consisting of $n$ points.
2. Determine all integers $n\ge 3$ for which there exists a balanced center-free set consisting of points.

Comment: This is the first problem of the first day of IMO 2015!

Comment: Lol,why are people voting to close under "unclear what you're asking"? That makes 0 sense

Comment: This is a cool question. What have you tried to answer it?

Comment: You can find answers here http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h1112746p5079638

Comment: I can give you instructions to find the solution: Prove center-free is possible for $n$ odd (easiest part of problem). Determine the solution for $n=4$, realize it is unique and not center-free and understand it thoroughly, expand it to $4+2$ and to $4+2+2\dots$. Realize the way to expand it always makes the set have a center.